# Mudar a cor de fundo do panel-heading ao clicar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

**HTML**

```
            <!-- panel 1 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default pulse animated">
                 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                      <h1 class="panel-title">
                        <a id="link-open" class="text-pan collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <center><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker gly-circle"></i></center>
                            <h2 id="title-cat">TÍTULO 01</h2>
                        </a>
                      </h1>    
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="panel-mob">
                      <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" src="imagens/background/screens-mob/bg-mob-one.jpg" />
                        <div class="caption-mob panel-body">
                          <h3 class="caption-title-mob animated fadeInDown">TÍTULO 01</h3>
                          <p class="caption-text-mob animated fadeInDown">texto aqui</p>
                          <a href="petbusca/pet.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-config btn-mob"><span class="animated rubberBand">acessar »</span></a>  
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / panel 1 -->

            <!-- panel 2 -->
            <div class="panel panel-default pulse animated">

              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                    <h1 class="panel-title">
                      <a id="link-open-two" class="text-pan collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                          <center><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home gly-circle"></i></center>
                          <h2 id="title-cat">TITULO</h2>
                      </a>
                    </h1>    
              </div>

              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body" id="panel-mob">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200" src="imagens/background/screens-mob/bg-mob-two.jpg" />
                    <div class="caption-mob panel-body">
                      <h3 class="caption-title-mob animated fadeInDown">TÍTULO 02</h3>
                      <p class="caption-text-mob animated fadeInDown">TEXTO AQUI</p>
                      <a href="vetemcasa/vet.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-config btn-mob"><span class="animated rubberBand">acessar »</span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / panel 2 -->           
        </div>
```

O código acima funciona como um accordion, é o mesmo code do accordion do Bootstrap. Gostaria de saber, como fazer para que o usuário ao clicar no "Panel-Heading", ele ficar com o fundo verde, e quando voltar ficar com o fundo branco, sem afetar o heading de baixo. Ou seja:

1. Antes de clicar ele estará com o fundo branco.
2. Depois que clicar ficará com o fundo verde.
3. Ao clicar novamente no link (heading) para fechar o mesmo depois de aberto, ou clicar no painel heading 2, ele ficará com o fundo branco novamente, e caso aconteça de o usuário clicar no link do heading do painel 2, ele irá executar as mesmas coisas que o link 1 do primeira panel-heading.
   que o link do accordion um, e vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Então, vou usar algo parecido, que to adpatando do script que postaram [neste link](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/bootstrap-3-accordian-onclick-accordion-background-should-be-change/98839/2), e acho que é quase exatamente o que vc quer. Na verdade foi só retirar o `in` do `colapse` em `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">`, para que o primeiro primeiro `panel` aparecesse fechado, e tirar o `highlight` de `<div class="panel-heading highlight">` pra que originalmente ele aparecesse em branco.

A única coisa é que quando ele fecha, ainda fica verde, mas dá uma olhada se te ajuda. Coloquei o snippet, então é só clicar aí embaixo em "Executar trecho de código".

```js
    function toggleChevron(e) {
          $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find('i.indicator')
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus');
            //$('#accordion .panel-heading').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('#accordion .panel-heading').removeClass('highlight');
        $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('highlight');
    }
    $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

```css
    .panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
     /* symbol for "opening" panels */
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
     content: "\e113";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
     float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
     color: black;         /* adjust as needed */
    }
    .panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
     /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
        content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    }
    .accordion-toggle:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
 #accordion .highlight {
     background:green;
     transition:background 2s ease;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #1 </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardsoad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #2 </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"> <i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #3 </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```